# I cannot get the vortex1.c file to compile, it also gives back an .o file when i'm trying to get an .exe file

Tags: c, compilation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define e(); 
if(((unsigned int)ptr & 0xff000000)==0xca000000) 
    { 
        setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid()); execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", NULL); 
}

void print(unsigned char *buf, int len)
{
        int i;

        printf("[ ");
        for(i=0; i < len; i++) printf("%x ", buf[i]);
        printf(" ]\n");
}

int main()
{
        unsigned char buf[512];
        unsigned char *ptr = buf + (sizeof(buf)/2);
        unsigned int x;

        while((x = getchar()) != EOF) {
                switch(x) {
                        case '\n': print(buf, sizeof(buf)); continue; break;
                        case '\\': ptr--; break;
                        default: e(); if(ptr > buf + sizeof(buf)) continue; ptr++[0] = x; break;
                }
        }
        printf("All done\n");
}
```

My errors include: |8|error: expected identifier or '(' before 'if'|

This is a direct copy from http://overthewire.org/wargames/vortex/vortex1.html so i assume the syntax is correct

Comment: It's not a direct copy... in the link, the `#define e();` and the four lines under it are on a single line.  If you want to break up a macro like that, you have to put a backslash before the line endings that are within the macro.

Comment: That semicolon after `e()` is puzzling/intriguing.  It is part of the expansion of `e()`.  It means there's an empty statement after the `default:` before the text of the macro.  Weird.  Harmless, but weird.

Comment: As Dmitri said, you need to put the expansion of e() in the same line or use backslash to escape the new line. Secondly can you mention how you are compiling the code? Flags would be useful. Since the file has errors I am sure it won't generate .o too. It could be a stray .o from before.

Answer (score 0):

What type of operating system are you on?  If you are trying to get an exe file and the program is referencing bash ("bin/bash") there will be some problems there.

Also, I believe that [unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) is a unix library and may be causing you some problems if you are on a Windows machine.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the author of this file had the macro all defined on one line and it looks like you have it broken up into two lines which may or may not be causing problems.  Just something to take a look at.

```
 #define e(); if(((unsigned int)ptr & 0xff000000)==0xca000000) { setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid()); execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-i", NULL); }
```

Comment: Ah i see being on windows must be my problem then, i'll try it in a VM

Comment: Yes, I would try that as a first shot.  From the command line you can do gcc -o vortex vortex1.c and then run ./vortex